# Spring + REST API. Создания скелета

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

Нужно создать рестовый скелет на основе спринг мвс, с чего начать? Как лучше конфигурировать? На чем вообще должно строится рест апи и нужно создавать его по образу какого-то специального архитипа или создавать обычный мавен проект и дальше постепенно все подключать?

Comment: что такое скилет?

Comment: Гуглите "spring rest github example". Берете любой понравившийся проект и допиливаете под свои нужды. Архетипы не нужны - `git clone` проще.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Нужно создать рестовый скелет на основе спринг мвс, с чего начать?

Советую с официального примера: https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/

> Как лучше конфигурировать?

Не думаю, что это важно, главное, чтобы работало и вы разбирались в вашем проекте. Но сейчас все бОльшую популярность набирает конфигурирование из java кода.

> На чем вообще должно строится рест апи и нужно создавать его по образу какого-то специального архитипа или создавать обычный мавен проект и дальше постепенно все подключать?

Зависит от вас, ваших знаний и задач. Я всегда придерживался второго подхода -- создавал минимально работающее и добавлял остальное по необходимости. Это, в том числе, помогает более-менее понимать что к чему относится. Но первый вариант с генерацией из архетипа тоже может быть полезен для быстрого старта.